# How can I find the node of the last layer of each tree in GBDT, using Spark MLLib?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I want to generate feature using GBDT (Facebook's paper [Practical Lessons from Predicting Clicks on Ads at Facebook](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=A54CCA7D4A8F05B6636C9D64316BCF96?doi=10.1.1.718.9050&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). And it seems easy to do this job, using Sklearn [Feature transformations with ensembles of trees](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_feature_transformation.html#example-ensemble-plot-feature-transformation-py). But using Spark to do this job seems hard since there is no method in Saprk's GBDT named `apply` (this method in `sklearn` can help me find the node) or some method that we can find the index of the leaf x ends up in each estimator, in another word, the node that data will be end up with in each estimator.

If I use the method `trees` in MLLib's GBDT Classifier model, then I get the following, which does not tell me the exactly node that I want to know

```
[DecisionTreeRegressionModel (uid=dtr_e1fb06f46c7c) of depth 2 with 5 nodes,
 DecisionTreeRegressionModel (uid=dtr_23641ea362dc) of depth 4 with 17 nodes,
 DecisionTreeRegressionModel (uid=dtr_3dedd910cbe2) of depth 3 with 7 nodes,
 DecisionTreeRegressionModel (uid=dtr_2cfe4fa44b89) of depth 3 with 9 nodes,
 DecisionTreeRegressionModel (uid=dtr_24c37bd33424) of depth 5 with 19 nodes,
 DecisionTreeRegressionModel (uid=dtr_4d7530bfc4e2) of depth 4 with 11 nodes,
 DecisionTreeRegressionModel (uid=dtr_e288599f5944) of depth 4 with 15 nodes,
 DecisionTreeRegressionModel (uid=dtr_d355940d4246) of depth 4 with 15 nodes,
 DecisionTreeRegressionModel (uid=dtr_6abbfbcfdd4e) of depth 3 with 9 nodes,
 DecisionTreeRegressionModel (uid=dtr_58ca63396c4a) of depth 3 with 13 nodes]
```

If I use `toDebugString`, then I get something like

```
u'GBTClassificationModel (uid=GBTClassifier_4f36b986f967194b34b6) with 10 trees\n  Tree 0 (weight 1.0):\n    If (feature 406 <= 72.0)\n     If (feature 99 in {2.0})\n      Predict: -1.0\n     Else (feature 99 not in {2.0})\n      Predict: 1.0\n    Else (feature 406 > 72.0)\n     Predict: -1.0\n  Tree 1 (weight 0.1):\n    If (feature 406 <= 72.0)\n     If (feature 209 <= 4.0)\n      Predict: -0.4768116880884702\n     Else (feature 209 > 4.0)\n      If (feature 236 <= 253.0)\n       If (feature 244 <= 175.0)\n        Predict: 0.4768116880884702\n       Else (feature 244 > 175.0)\n        Predict: 0.47681168808847024\n      Else (feature 236 > 253.0)\n       Predict: 0.4768116880884703\n    Else (feature 406 > 72.0)\n     If (feature 459 <= 144.0)\n      If (feature 323 <= 78.0)\n       If (feature 119 in {0.0})\n        Predict: -0.4768116880884702\n       Else (feature 119 not in {0.0})\n        Predict: -0.4768116880884701\n      Else (feature 323 > 78.0)\n       If (feature 323 <= 116.0)\n        Predict: -0.4768116880884702\n       Else (feature 323 > 116.0)\n        Predict: -0.47681168808847035\n     Else (feature 459 > 144.0)\n      Predict: -0.4768116880884712\n  Tree 2 (weight 0.1):\n    If (feature 406 <= 72.0)\n     If (feature 209 <= 4.0)\n      Predict: -0.4381935810427206\n     Else (feature 209 > 4.0)\n      If (feature 578 <= 13.0)\n       Predict: 0.4381935810427206\n      Else (feature 578 > 13.0)\n       Predict: 0.4381935810427206\n    Else (feature 406 > 72.0)\n     Predict: -0.43819358104272055\n  Tree 3 (weight 0.1):\n    If (feature 433 <= 0.0)\n     If (feature 239 <= 253.0)\n      Predict: 0.40514968028459825\n     Else (feature 239 > 253.0)\n      Predict: -0.4051496802845982\n    Else (feature 433 > 0.0)\n     If (feature 124 <= 26.0)\n      If (feature 265 <= 3.0)\n       Predict: -0.40514968028459825\n      Else (feature 265 > 3.0)\n       Predict: -0.4051496802845982\n     Else (feature 124 > 26.0)\n      Predict: -0.4051496802845984\n
```

It is hard for my code to find the place of node in the last layer of each tree.

How can I generate feature using Spark's GBDT, just like what sklearn can do ?

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this?